# Audio capabilities not being detected properly

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Built a new computer that is a dual-boot Win7 and Ubuntu 14.04.  My motherboard has onboard 5.1/8.1 audio capability, which works fine on windows, but is only detected as a basic audio out on Ubuntu.  After some investigation I found that it uses the acl891 codec.  Support for this codec was included in the linux kernel 3.8.y update stream.

Am I missing something I should have installed/enabled?  I do have sound, but would like to use my 5.1 speakers, as I do watch movies on my computer, and currently only have a single channel out enabled.  The motherboard does use dual use jacks - mic and line in doubling as subwoofer out and centre out.  Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install `pavucontrol`,

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Now choose desired configuration from the 'Configuration' tab.